# Split certain words from a variable

Tags: jquery, html

I have a variable with the following value,

```
var dataIn = <hr data-type="google">Google;
```

I want split the hr `(<hr data-type="google">)` from the above variable and store into a new var called 'hr'

please help me do this.

Comment: var hr=value.split(" ")[0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dataIn = '<hr data-type="google">Google';
var str = dataIn.split(">")[0]+">";
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/jbzHk/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use:

```
var dataIn = '<hr data-type="google">Google';

var hr = dataIn.split(">")[0]+">";
```

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/BKBJN/

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it in the jQuery way, without any string manipulation:

```
var dataIn = '<hr data-type="google">Google;';
var oDiv = $("<div></div>").html(dataIn);
var hr = oDiv.find("hr");
var raw = (hr.length === 1) ? hr[0].outerHTML : "";
alert(raw);
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/u4bh9/).

Answer (score 1):

```
var hr = dataIn.split(">")[0]+">"
```

Or :

```
var hr = dataIn.split("Google")[0]
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, fixing this because it wasn't in code format.

```
var dataIn = "<hr data-type=\"google\">Google";
var regexp = new RegExp(/<.*>/gi);

var hr = dataIn.match( regexp )[0];
```